# Почему страницы персонального раздела выдают 404?

Tags: битрикс

после сохранения через админку страницы персонального раздела стали выдавать 404 ,как поправить и почему такое случилось?
вернул эту страницу из сохраненной копии ,но ссылки так и не заработали
посмотрел в папке персонального раздела нет этих страниц ,но компонент код которого ниже сам подставляет под эти урлы нужные страницы,но почему это  перестало работать?

https://shop.mercury-market.ru/personal/orders/
https://shop.mercury-market.ru/personal/private/
https://shop.mercury-market.ru/personal/orders/?filter_history=Y

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:sale.personal.section", 
    "bootstrap_v4", 
    array(
        "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_ELIMINATED_PAY_SYSTEMS" => array(
            0 => "0",
        ),
        "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_PERSON_TYPE" => "1",
        "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_SELL_CURRENCY" => "RUB",
        "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_SELL_SHOW_FIXED_VALUES" => "N",
        "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_SELL_TOTAL" => array(
            0 => "100",
            1 => "200",
            2 => "500",
            3 => "1000",
            4 => "5000",
            5 => "",
        ),
        "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT_SELL_USER_INPUT" => "Y",
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "ALLOW_INNER" => "Y",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_RIGHTS_PRIVATE" => "N",
        "COMPATIBLE_LOCATION_MODE_PROFILE" => "N",
        "CUSTOM_PAGES" => "[]",
        "CUSTOM_SELECT_PROPS" => array(
        ),
        "MAIN_CHAIN_NAME" => "Личный кабинет",
        "NAV_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "ONLY_INNER_FULL" => "Y",
        "ORDERS_PER_PAGE" => "20",
        "ORDER_DEFAULT_SORT" => "STATUS",
        "ORDER_DISALLOW_CANCEL" => "N",
        "ORDER_HIDE_USER_INFO" => array(
            0 => "0",
        ),
        "ORDER_HISTORIC_STATUSES" => array(
        ),
        "ORDER_REFRESH_PRICES" => "N",
        "ORDER_RESTRICT_CHANGE_PAYSYSTEM" => array(
            0 => "F",
        ),
        "PATH_TO_BASKET" => SITE_DIR."basket/",
        "PATH_TO_CATALOG" => SITE_DIR."catalog/",
        "PATH_TO_CONTACT" => SITE_DIR."about/contacts/",
        "PATH_TO_PAYMENT" => SITE_DIR."personal/order/payment/",
        "PROFILES_PER_PAGE" => "20",
        "PROP_1" => array(
        ),
        "SAVE_IN_SESSION" => "Y",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SEND_INFO_PRIVATE" => "N",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT" => "Y",
        "SHOW_ACCOUNT_PAGE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_ACCOUNT_PAY_COMPONENT" => "Y",
        "SHOW_BASKET_PAGE" => "N",
        "SHOW_CONTACT_PAGE" => "N",
        "SHOW_ORDER_PAGE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_PRIVATE_PAGE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_PROFILE_PAGE" => "N",
        "SHOW_SUBSCRIBE_PAGE" => "N",
        "USE_AJAX_LOCATIONS_PROFILE" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "bootstrap_v4",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => SITE_DIR."personal/",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "index" => "index.php",
            "orders" => "orders/",
            "account" => "account/",
            "subscribe" => "subscribe/",
            "profile" => "profiles/",
            "profile_detail" => "profiles/#ID#",
            "private" => "private/",
            "order_detail" => "orders/#ID#",
            "order_cancel" => "cancel/#ID#",
        )
    ),
    false
);?>

<?php if($APPLICATION->GetCurDir() != SITE_DIR.'personal/'){?></div></div><?}?>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как решили проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего перезаписался файл urlrewrite.php

А вот что там у вас было, сказать сложно. Судя по виду ссылок, возможно, что-то подобное

```
0 => [
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/order/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.order',
    'PATH' => '/personal/order/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
]
```